# TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module Error Using Spark, Livy, Sparkmagic

Tags: pyspark, livy

where if I run my code as follows in separate cells line-by-line, there is no error like

- using Jupyter notebook code block

`import sys`

> 

`print(sys.version)`

> 3.8.9 ..

But, when i write code together like this,

```
import sys
sys.version
```

required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/362488836129912165", line 215, in execute
code = compile(mod, self.cell_name, 'exec')
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module

raise this error.

My Python version : 3.8.13
IPython version : 8.3.0
Spark Version : 3.2.2
using Sparkmagic : 0.20.5

Any idea..?

My Python version : 3.8.13
IPython version : 8.3.0
Spark Version : 3.2.2

My env connect spark using livy + sparkmagic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is caused by old `livy` version. It was fixed in 0.8.0 https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/314.